# usar COUNT e inserir DIV de X em X quantidade

Tags: php

Supondo que eu tenha um banco de dados com X elementos! No momento da query vou usar um `count` para ver quantas linhas eu tenho! Gostaria de dividir esse resultado e dividir por um numero qualquer, nesse caso vou usar o valor de 3,levando em consideração que tive um retorno de 9 linhas, o resultado será 3!

Então no momento do `echo` gostaria de inserir uma pra `div` em "volta" de cada 3 resultados. Gostaria que o resultado ficasse parecido com o seguinte!

```
<div class="inserida_pela_php">
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 1 </div>
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 2 </div>
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 3 </div>
</div>

<div class="inserida_pela_php">
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 4 </div>
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 5 </div>
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 6 </div>
</div>

<div class="inserida_pela_php">
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 7 </div>
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 8 </div>
    <div class="div_qualquer"> 9 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="inserida_pela_php">
<?php
$count = 9;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="div_qualquer">' . $i . '</div>' . "\n";
    if ($i % 3 == 0 && $i != $count) {
        echo '</div><div class="inserida_pela_php">' . "\n";
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

Ajuste para suas necessidades

Comment: Otimo! Vou até estudar mais com esse trecho seu!

Comment: Infelizmente eu n lembro como isso se chama, mas quando você usa % ele divide e retorna o resto, tipo 9%8=1

Comment: Só complementando: `%` Significa _Módulo_ , é um dos operadores aritméticos!  ele retorna o resto de uma divisão, `$a % $b` o resultado será o resto de `$a` dividido por `$b`.

Comment: To precisando acrescentar uma consulta ao banco de de dados!! E distribuir  os dados entre as colunas! Eu usei! Mas em vez de distribuir os 18 resultados pelas div! Ele ta repitindo tudo em cada vez que a div "inserida_pela_php"

Comment: Posta em algum lugar o código que você tem até agora e talvez eu possa ajudar.